# lift Session management

Tags: lift

I am new to lift. I have been working with MVC model so far and using basic session management model i.e. storing a token in the session and check on each request.
I am trying to do the same with lift, but my session getting expired abruptly. even some time I just logged in and it logged out. I have analysis that whenever I gets log message like this:
 `INFO -  Session ucjrn5flnq9q1ke52z5zixgtt expired`

I have searched but I couldn't find any step by step tutor

Answer (score 2):

Sessions are managed by your servlet container. Which one are you using? You should look at the container's documentation.

Comment: Thanks for response. I am using embedded Jetty web container. And I have been working with jetty for long with normal J2ee application and they work fine. Is there something to do with Lift, like it needs some special implementation I'll have to do?

Comment: How do you store/check for the session data? Without more information this is difficult do diagnose. Usually sessions should just work without any extra work.

Comment: I am using embedded Jetty, where I am using ServletContextHandler to registered lift filter. I want to avoid making war file and than deploy the application. Instead of that I just want all the unit to be run as single jar file.

Answer (score 2):

Do not attempt to use S.get et al to access session bound information. This is just plain dangerous. Do it like this:

```
class Thing {
  object SessionThing extends SessionVar[Box[String]](Empty)
  ...
  def someMethod = {
    ...
    SessionThing.is // returns you a Box[String].
    // operates on the session variable if it exists, 
    // otherwise provides a sensible default
    SessionThing.is.map(_.toLowerCase).openOr("default") 
    ...
  }
}
```

You need to understand the snippet and state lifecycles really, as it seems you're not fully understanding how lift's session mechanics work.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution of the problem. I was using embedded jetty server, where I was using ServletContextHandler to register lift filter. I changed it to WebAppContext and it started working fine.

Puneet